# Subtract values in same column from 2 different dates in same Mysql table

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, join, query

I have a MySql table like:

```
Item        Date          Likes

Book        2012-05-20    402
Book        2012-05-21    432
Book        2012-05-22    450
Pen         2012-05-20    20
Pen         2012-05-21    20
Pen         2012-05-22    25
```

1) What is the simplest query for calculating and returning the difference in `Likes` column between 2 set dates for all of the `Item` values, ordered by the Difference?

For example:

`Likes` difference between 2012-05-20 and 2012-05-21 returns next results:

```
Item        Difference
Book        30
Pen         0
```

`Likes` difference between 2012-05-20 and 2012-05-22 returns next results:

```
Item        Difference
Book        48
Pen         5
```

2) Also there will be some cases when there will be no records for some of the dates for an `Item` in the table, in those cases no results for that `Item` should be returned.

3) What should be the correct indices to optimize the speed of the query?

I did come across [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310221/sql-subtract-two-rows-based-on-date-and-another-column) that might work but it is a huge query and I am sure that there can be a more compact and elegant solution :)

Comment: What version MYSQL? Newest version has window functions.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I think window funcs usage is excess on that task... the dates are set directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.item, t2.likes - t1.likes difference
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.item = t2.item
  AND t1.date = @first_date
  AND t2.date = @second_date
```

If you need all items (ever the data on @first_date or @second_date is not present), rewrite from cartesian to FULL JOIN and use COALESCE to replace NULLs with zeros.

Comment: It works great! Before I accept, what column should I put index on to optimize the query speed?

Comment: @Acidon *what column should I put index on to optimize the query speed?* It is difficult to answer. If items count is not too large maybe the index by date is enough, else the index by (date, item) may be more suitable. If record size is large (there is a lot of non-shown fields) maybe the index by (date, item, likes) will be the best. Test in practice.